# java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException shown when trying to Assert some values

Tags: java

I am using the below code to assert text in my test script. But its giving UnsupportedOperationException error every time it hits this code.

```
public static void verifyEquals(Object actual, Object expected) {
        try {
            Assert.assertEquals(actual, expected);
        } catch(Throwable e) {
            addVerificationFailure(e);
        }
    }

    public static List<Throwable> getVerificationFailures() {
        List verificationFailures = verificationFailuresMap.get(Reporter.getCurrentTestResult());
        return verificationFailures == null ? new ArrayList() : verificationFailures;
    }

    private static void addVerificationFailure(Throwable e) {
        StackTraceElement[] error = e.getStackTrace();
        List<StackTraceElement> errors = Arrays.asList(error);
        verificationFailuresMap.put(Reporter.getCurrentTestResult(), errors);
        List verificationFailures = getVerificationFailures();
        verificationFailuresMap.put(Reporter.getCurrentTestResult(), verificationFailures);
        verificationFailures.add(e);
    }
```

Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: And on which line is it throwing the exception?

Comment: Test code should not be as complex as this. *Quis custodiet ipsos custodes?*

Comment: And why are you using raw types?

Answer (score 2):

This is the problem:

```
List verificationFailures = getVerificationFailures();
verificationFailuresMap.put(Reporter.getCurrentTestResult(), verificationFailures);
verificationFailures.add(e);
```

You're calling `List.add` on the result of `Arrays.asList`. You can't do that, as the result of `Arrays.asList` is a *view* onto the array - you can't add or remove elements.

Additionally - erasure aside - that list is a `List<StackTraceElement>` - it's backed by a `StackTraceElement[]`. What does it even mean to add a `Throwable` to that?

It's simpler to see the problem if you remove the code which puts the list into the map and then fetches it back again before adding:

```
private static void addVerificationFailure(Throwable e) {
    StackTraceElement[] error = e.getStackTrace();
    List<StackTraceElement> errors = Arrays.asList(error);
    verificationFailuresMap.put(Reporter.getCurrentTestResult(), errors);
    errors.add(e);
}
```

This will now fail at *compile* time due to trying to add a `Throwable` to a `List<StackTraceElement>`. But even if you were trying to add a `StackTraceElement` it would *still* fail due to `Arrays.asList` not supporting `add`.

It's really unclear what you're trying to do, but you need to rethink it...

Comment: +1 Or in other words (if I got it right), `Arrays.asList()` returns a fixed-size list - and we cannot add elements to a fixed size list.

Comment: Thanks Jon for such lighting response. I was actually following this link: http://seleniumexamples.com/blog/guide/using-soft-assertions-in-testng/ to use Soft Assertions in my test scripts. But the snippet was not working so I made some changes. Also I being new to Java is not aware much of the stuff.

Comment: @alfasin: That's *one* of the problems, yes.

Comment: @ss.: That at least explains the `actual`/`expected` ordering - TestNG uses that approach, but JUnit (the more common framework) uses the reverse order.